# {Basic Question} Applying Image grid with Bootstrap ( Thumbnail Issue)

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

How to create a grid of images using bootstrap?

Thats what i got when i try the next codes

[image: What i get]

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://scx2.b-cdn.net/gfx/news/hires/2019/2-nature.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Im still in the very first steps learning phase started with HTML CSS and bootstrap as it give us achievements to feel the process.

im expecting to get thumbnail of grids as the following image[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it like this...

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <img src="https://scx2.b-cdn.net/gfx/news/hires/2019/2-nature.jpg" class="thumbnail">
    </div>
</div>
```

Then when adding extra pics, put them in columns too.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <img src="https://scx2.b-cdn.net/gfx/news/hires/2019/2-nature.jpg" class="thumbnail">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <img src="https://scx2.b-cdn.net/gfx/news/hires/2019/2-nature.jpg" class="thumbnail">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <img src="https://scx2.b-cdn.net/gfx/news/hires/2019/2-nature.jpg" class="thumbnail">
    </div>
</div>
```

It may then work even better if you add widths to those columns using `col-*` where * is any number between 1 and 12.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
        <img src="https://scx2.b-cdn.net/gfx/news/hires/2019/2-nature.jpg" class="thumbnail">
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <img src="https://scx2.b-cdn.net/gfx/news/hires/2019/2-nature.jpg" class="thumbnail">
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <img src="https://scx2.b-cdn.net/gfx/news/hires/2019/2-nature.jpg" class="thumbnail">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This one worked but i need to know the different between 
'<div class="col-3">
        <img src="https://scx2.b-cdn.net/gfx/news/hires/2019/2-nature.jpg" class="thumbnail">
    </div>'

and this
'<div class="col">
        <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://scx2.b-cdn.net/gfx/news/hires/2019/2-nature.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>'

Comment: i want to know more info and different between 
adding the thumbnail after img than adding the img in the thum class?

Comment: By using the columns you  may find that you do not need to use `class="thumbnail"` in any way. `class="img-fluid` would work well though. My best recommend is to follow the notes at GetBootstrap. There is a lot you can simply copy and paste and then edit to your needs but it's good for general learning as well. Everything you need to know is in the left menu. This is for Bootstrap version 5 -  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/columns/

Comment: Where `col` has been used here to create a layout, they could also be Bootstrap `card`s inside a `row` instead of columns, or maybe you want cards inside columns...

Comment: All comments worked thanks guys <3